# Check Radio button on div click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like radio button to check/uncheck whenever i click it's parent div.
Radio buttons are originally hidden.

I was trying to achieve that by wrapping `<label>` around the div. It works, but `jQ.toggleClass` stops working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="big">
This is a div 1
<input id="chb" type="radio" />
</div>

<br/>

<div class="big">
This is a div 2
<input id="chb" type="radio" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big {

    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.hli {

    border:2px solid blue;

}

/*.chb{display:none;}*/
```

**JQ**

```
$('.big').click(function() {
$('.hli').toggleClass('hli');   
$(this).toggleClass('hli');
});
```

> **JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/QqVCu/2/**

Comment: I reedited my answer in a CSS fashion. take a look ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about that: http://jsfiddle.net/sgospodarets/QqVCu/5/ ? 
All that is necessary - wrap inputs in label. Then do not need JavaScipt.

Comment: Yes, works perfect, but i think i still need javascript for borders. Like I said, radios are originally hidden, so there has to be some visual proof.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options > "Validate HTML fragment"
doesn't think so.
He says "This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.01 Strict!"

Comment: you just taught me the secrets of css!

Answer (score 10):

Using a pure HTML/CSS solution:

```css
.isHidden {
  display: none; /* hide radio buttons */
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.radio:checked + .label {   /* target next sibling (+) label */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio_1" class="radio isHidden" name="radio_a" type="radio">
<label for="radio_1" class="label">1</label>

<input id="radio_2" class="radio isHidden" name="radio_a" type="radio">
<label for="radio_2" class="label">2</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tell me that if u want this: http://jsfiddle.net/QqVCu/6/

**jQuery** (Updated)

```js
$('.big').click(function() {
    if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){
       $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
       $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
    $('.hli').toggleClass('hli');    
    $(this).toggleClass('hli');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `prop()` method, try the following:

```
$('.big').click(function() {
  $('.hli').removeClass('hli');
  $(this).addClass('hli').find('input').prop('checked', true)    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QqVCu/4/)

*please note that IDs must be unique and in order to work properly radio buttons should have name properties:*

```
<input id="chb1" type="radio" name="radioGroup"/>
<input id="chb2" type="radio" name="radioGroup"/>
```

Comment: This works very good together with CF7 in Wordpress. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuXvM/

To have a single radio button checked, you should group them by name (give same name for all the buttons that are part of the group)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QqVCu/50/

To bypass jQuery event bubbling I've used regular JS to trigger the click().

```
$('.big').click(function () {
    $('.hli').toggleClass('hli');
    $(this).toggleClass('hli');
    var Id = $(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr('id');
    document.getElementById(Id).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery, this is how you should do it

```
$('.big').on({
    click: function () {

      $('.hli').toggleClass('hli');
      $(this).toggleClass('hli');

    }
}, 'input[name="chb"]');
```